# Strange C code compiling under avr-gcc when it should not

Tags: c

Hey can someone please tell me what this code is meant to be doing, or how this syntax is even allowed to compile under avr-gcc? It is code taken from NanoVM source code, compiling it for the avr atmega128rfa1.

// buffer for file itself is in eeprom

```
ifdef NVM_USE_FLASH_PROGRAM
static u08_t nvmfile[CODESIZE] PROGMEM =
#include "nvmdefault.h"
#else
static u08_t EEPROM nvmfile[CODESIZE] =
#include "nvmdefault.h"
#endif
```

Note I am not compiling this with -DNVM_USE_FLASH_PROGRAM

Comment: I suspect the missing hash at the beginning of the first line of code is a typo, isn't it?

Comment: We need to see the content of `nvmdefault.h` to judge whether this shall compile or not.

Comment: use flag -E to find out.

Answer (score 5):

If `nvmdefault.h` includes an array initializer then this code should compile fine, something like this:

```
nvmdefault.h
{0x01, 0x02, 0x03, etc...};
```

As for what it does exactly, you have to look at the source code to be sure, but it looks like it's allocating that array on either Flash or EEPROM memory, also, there's probably a good reason to write it like that, e.g. the array is generated by another program or script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in compilation of this code, as far as `"nvmdefault.h"` begins with definition of the initializer list, as

```
{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Then your source will be preprocessed into this (let's say `NVM_USE_FLASH_PROGRAM` is defined):

```
static u08_t nvmfile[CODESIZE] PROGMEM =
{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

and this is a valid C code.

Consider this file called `dirtyc.c`:

```
#ifndef C_IS_DIRTY
    #define C_IS_DIRTY
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main (void)
    #include "dirtyc.c"
#else
    { printf("hello dirty world!\n"); return 0; }
#endif
```

Comment: Just because the code compiles doesn't make it sane or good practice. Indeed C allows a lot of crazy stuff, so you can replace C_IS_DIRTY with `__STDC__`.

Comment: @Lundin I do not say that it is a good practice. I just want to show a similar example

Comment: You did say that you don't see any problems with the code. But what you most likely meant was that you don't see any problems with getting it to compile:)

Comment: Yep makes perfect sense, and yes @Lundin that is what I meant. :) thank you guys.